# Difference importing template from lodash and lodash/template?

Tags: javascript, templates, import, lodash

Is there a difference importing "template" from lodash like this:

```
import { template } from 'lodash';
```

Or like this:

```
import template from 'lodash/template';
```

The first alternative works fine but the second alternative throws TypeError when I use other lodash functions like _.isString inside the templates.

> Uncaught TypeError: _.isString is not a function
>       at eval (eval at  (template.js:225), :10:13)

If I debug inside the eval, the _ (underscore) object looks like this:

```
Object {escape: function}
    escape: function escape(string)
    __proto__: Object
```

Empty except for an escape function?

I would like to use lodash/core and cherrypick non-core functions such as "template", but this makes it hard.

Environment:

- Webpack 1.13.0
- Babel 6.24.1
- Backbone 1.3.3
- Lodash 4.17.4

Comment: For me `import template from 'lodash/template'` doesn't work: `Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\lodash.template\index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who happens to run into this, even in 2020:

Webpack, babel, etc. in combination bastardize lodash (and every other library) they "precompile". The expected object instances and behavior aren't available to you when you build your templates. For example, `_.forEach` may get "optimized" to  be `lodash_forEach__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default` in memory. So if you attempt to use the expected instantiation of lodash, "_", in any script that isn't "precompiled" into the same babel script pipeline, it will be unavailable (which I suppose makes sense for SPAs).

In order to "use" any "optimized" behavior, you'll need to pass in the behavior explicitly. This way, when webpack and babel do their thing, the correct function gets projected into the template runtime.

```
 var template = $('#template').html(),
        compiled = _.template(template, { 'imports': { 'each': _.forEach } });
```

Then in your template:

```
<% each(items, function(item) { %><li><%- item %></li><% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround by using templateSettings.imports in _.template and basically importing lodash into the template processing eval.

```
const templateSettings = { imports: { _: _ } };
const processedTemplate = template(templateToProcess, templateSettings)(data);
```

Here is the Lodash documentation for template and templateSettings:
https://lodash.com/docs/latest#template

I still don't know why the underscore global is empty in the eval when using the cheerypicked template import, though...